Weird behavior of Flutter list-view. It overflows its bounds
I observed some weird behavior of Flutter's list view. It overflows it's boundary. I basically needed a screen with a heading area, a list-view in the middle and a footer. I enclosed the three sections each in a SizedBox. However, the listview overflows its sized box while repainting. Below is the code I used and see the screenshot of what I observe.
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestData {
  String name;
  String description;

  TestData({required this.name, required this.description});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return "name: $name description: $description";
  }
}

final List<TestData> testData = [
  TestData(name: "Item 1", description: "description for item 1"),
  TestData(name: "Item 2", description: "description for item 1"),
  TestData(name: "Item 3", description: "description for item 1"),
  TestData(name: "Item 4", description: "description for item 1"),
  TestData(name: "Item 5", description: "description for item 1"),
  TestData(name: "Item 6", description: "description for item 1"),
  TestData(name: "Item 7", description: "description for item 1"),
  TestData(name: "Item 8", description: "description for item 1"),
  TestData(name: "Item 9", description: "description for item 1"),
];

class ListWithHeader extends StatelessWidget {
  const ListWithHeader({super.key});

  Widget _header(BuildContext context) {
    return const Text("This is the header");
  }

  Widget _footer(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        color: Colors.green.shade100,
        child: const Text("This is the footer"));
  }

  Widget _listBody(BuildContext context) {
    print("Item count :$testData.length");
    return ListView.separated(
      itemCount: testData.length,
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        TestData td = testData[index];
        print("ListTile for index $index and td: $td");
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(td.name),
          subtitle: Text(td.description),
          tileColor: Colors.pink.shade100,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("ListWithHeader"),
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          return SizedBox(
            height: constraints.maxHeight,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: constraints.maxHeight * .2,
                  child: Container(
                      //alignment: Alignment.center,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: _header(context)),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  //height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.5,
                  child: _listBody(
                      context), //_bodyText(context) //_listBody(context),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                    height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.2,
                    child: _footer(context)),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


Anyone know if I am doing something wrong or is this a bug?
Screenshot showing ListView overflow

first, using LayoutBuilder is unnecessary.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("ListWithHeader"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: _header(context),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: _listBody(context),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: _footer(context),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

second, try adding padding: EdgeInsets.zero to the ListView

Thanks. But why does the listview overflow it's bounds! Seems to be an issue with the scrolling.

it seems that the problem is that the header do not take the full width he can take - try put it in a center and if it doesn't work, put it in a sizedbox with width of double.infinity
